# `body` of `inbox_item` returning only excerpt, not full body

Tags: support, api-v2.2, inbox

I have run [/inbox/unread](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread) function. It returns a list of [inbox_item](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item)s.

The `body` of `inbox_item` gives excerpt, not the full body. This is with all the functions that return `inbox_item`.

According to me this is a bug. Is this the expected behavior?

In case of [/me/questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-questions), `body` of [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) is coming as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inbox message `body` is not the same as a post `body`.  **Inbox messages are truncated by design.**

Here's a snippet of my inbox:

> [image: inbox]

Notice how **the "body" is truncated at 100 characters?** (Counting the `...` and accounting for HTML entities like `&#39;`.)

The results I get from [/2.2/me/inbox?filter=!SmOhH2b13NujlyyXX6](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox#filter=!SmOhH2b13NujlyyXX6&site=stackoverflow) are exactly the same:

```
"body": "Very good. I&#39;m not an expert on user scripts after all. Good job.",
...
"body": "Aah, thnaks. The original answer didn&#39;t have that information (as linked) but it&#39;s quite ...",
...
"body": "@BrockAdams Ah, that&#39;s what I suspected. Sorry, I&#39;m veering from the original question at...",
...
```

**There is no bug here.**

Comment: It would be good if there was uniformity. Somewhere it is truncated, other places it is not.

Comment: Inbox items have always been truncated so. Where is it not truncated and the source text was more than 100 characters? Show a counterexample, if you have one.

Comment: I meant to say in `body` of `inbox_items` it is truncated. In `body` of `question` it is not truncated. I was taking about this uniformity.

Comment: It's apples and oranges.  They both are called "body" but they are not the same thing.  It's rather like you should "cleave" to your wife, but you should never "cleave" her in two (unless the {censored} is asking for it).  Same word, two very different things.